# Calculating $\int_{e^2}^{e^3} \frac{1}{x \ln(x)\ln(\ln(x))} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

We want to calculate

$$\int_{e^2}^{e^3} \frac{1}{x \ln(x)\ln(\ln(x))} dx = \int_2^3 \frac{1}{e^t \cdot t \cdot \ln(t)} \cdot e^t dt = \int_2^3 \frac{1}{t \ln(t)} dt = \int_2^3 \frac{\frac{1}{t}}{\ln(t)} \\ = \ln(\ln(3)) - \ln(\ln(2))$$

How does one get to the second part? Why can we change the upper bounds to $2$ and $3$ correspondingly?

$$ \int_2^3 \frac{1}{e^t \cdot t \cdot \ln(t)} \cdot e^t dt $$

What is this method called? Is it just a variant of integration by substitution? Are there other examples of this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let $x= e^t$ and start substituting....

Comment: And where does the $e^t$ before $dt$ come from?

Comment: $dx = e^t \ dt$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to rote substitution.

Substitute $\color{red}{t=\ln(x)}$ and $\color{blue}{dt=\frac{dx}x}$. The limits change to $x=e^2\implies t=\ln(e^2)=2$ and $x=e^3\implies t=\ln(e^3)=3$.

$$\int_{x=e^2}^{e^3} \frac{\color{blue}{dx}}{\color{blue}{x}\color{red}{\ln(x)}\ln(\color{red}{\ln(x)})} = \int_{t=2}^3 \frac{\color{blue}{dt}}{\color{red}t \ln(\color{red}t)}$$

Or equivalently, let $\color{red}{x=e^t}$ and $\color{blue}{dx=e^t\,dt}$.

$$\int_{x=e^2}^{e^3} \frac{\color{blue}{dx}}{\color{red}{x}\ln(\color{red}{x})\ln(\ln(\color{red}{x}))} = \int_{t=2}^3 \frac{\color{blue}{e^t\,dt}}{\color{red}{e^t} \ln(\color{red}{e^t})\ln(\ln(\color{red}{e^t}))} = \int_{t=2}^3 \frac{dt}{t \ln(t)}$$

since $\ln(e^t)=t\ln(e)=t$.

Answer (score 2):

Note $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln(\ln(x))\right)=\frac{1}{x\ln(x)}$

Let $u=\ln(\ln(x))$ and $du=\frac{1}{x\ln(x)}dx$

Bounds go to $\ln 2$ and $\ln 3$

$$\implies\int_{\ln 2}^{\ln{3}}\frac{1}{u}\;du$$

Can you continue?